# Is this a valid proof that $A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\,=\left(A\cup B\right)\cap\left(A\cup C\right)?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm an undergraduate taking a course in discrete mathematics and I recently ran into this problem on my homework:

> Prove $A\cup\left(B\cap C\right) = \left(A\cup B\right)\cap\left(A\cup C\right)$

I ended up coming up with two proofs, the first is correct and not that interesting, but my second attempt was different. It is:

> Proof: Let $P,Q,$ and $R$ be predicates defined:
>
> - $P\left(x\right)=x\in A$
> - $Q\left(x\right)  =  x\in B$
> - $R\left(x\right)  =  x\in C$
>
> By substitution and the definitions of intersection and union, we can
> rewrite $A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)$ as a logical equivalence:
> $$P\left(x\right)  \lor\left(Q\left(x\right)  \land R\left(x\right)\right).$$
> Applying the same logic to $\left(A\cup B\right)  \cap  \left(A\cup C\right)$ gives:
> $$\left(P\left(x\right)\lor Q\left(x\right)\right)  \land\left(P\left(x\right)\lor R\left(x\right)\right).$$
> Now suppose $n  \in  \mathbb{U},$ then $n  \in A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)$    iff $P\left(n\right)  \lor\left(Q\left(n\right)  \land R\left(n\right)\right)$.
>
> Similarly, $n  \in\left(A\cup B\right)  \cap  \left(A\cup C\right)$  iff $\left(P\left(n\right)\lor Q\left(n\right)\right)  \land\left(P\left(n\right)\lor R\left(n\right)\right).$
>
> Finally, notice that:
> $P\left(x\right)  \lor\left(Q\left(x\right)  \land R\left(x\right)\right)\equiv\left(P\left(x\right)\lor Q\left(x\right)\right)  \land\left(P\left(x\right)\lor R\left(x\right)\right)$  by Distributive Law.
>
> Therefore,  $A\cup\left(B\cap C\right)  =\left(A\cup B\right)\cap\left(A\cup C\right)$
>
> $\square$

My thought process here was that I could substitute the set operations for their logical definitions. I haven't really been able to figure out if this proof is any good or not but I feel like I might at least be onto something.

Comment: $$\text{Why type like this?}$$

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to LaTex as well as set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conventional strategy sufficient to verify that two sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are equal is:
$$x \in \mathcal{A} \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{B}.$$

In this way, the case cited by you is enough to do:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x \in A \cup (B \cap C) & \Leftrightarrow & x \in A \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ x \in B \cap C\\
& \Leftrightarrow & x \in A \ \ \mbox{or} \ \ (x \in B \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ x \in C)\\
& \Leftrightarrow & x \in (A \ \mbox{or} \ B) \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ x \in (A \ \mbox{or} \ C)\\
& \Leftrightarrow & x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if setting up a simple set theory proof using logical tautologies is "interesting" or "boring". The stanbard proof would be a simple "two inclusions" proof with some case distinguishing for the unions.
I think that would be the text book's idea of how the proof ought to be done.

So ask yourself: what's goal of this exercise?

Comment: Why would you do it that way?  If you allow reasoning about elements, why not use logical equivalence and extensionality, like @M.F.? Alternatively, if you insist on set algebra and antisymmetry, you get a nice little exercise, but not an especially simple proof.